# FCM Messages are received only on some of the devices, not all

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

For messaging to my Android apps from the cloud, I am using the golang library for sending messages *messaging.Client. When I have messages to send I use the API "Send" on the Client library. It does not return any error. It returns a message ID something like:

```
projects/[projectId]/messages/58548577208715XXXX
```

What we have noticed is that some devices get messages, some do not. We've verified that the devices that did not receive messages are not in Doze mode, Cloud messages are not blocked, and are connected to the Internet, running recent Android OS versions if not the latest.

Is there a way to investigate further using the message ID "58548577208715XXXX" returned?
The FCM Console has no mention of the messages sent... even for the older messages, even though many messages were sent and received on Android devices.